# how to deploy function using serverless so that it includes only required folder/files

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, serverless-framework

```
    |--serverless.yml
    |--lib/
    |--node_modules/
    |--api/
        |--manageclient/
            |--addClient/
                |--handler.js
```

This is my folder structure , 
how to deploy function using serverless so that it includes only handler.js and node_modules/ and lib/.

Can you please specify the function command to be written on main serverless.yml?

My YML function statement

```
handler: api/manageclient/addClient/addclient.addclient
   package:
     exclude:
       - ./*
       - !api/manageclient/addClient/**
       - !api/node_modules/**
       - !api/lib/**
```

Answer (score 5):

This is my structure:

```
package:
  individually: true
  exclude:
    - ./**
```

and in my function:

```
functions:
  lambda:
    handler: dist/index.handler
    package:
      include:
        - 'dist/**/*'
        - '!dist/**/*.map'
        - '!node_modules/aws-sdk/**/*'
```

First you tell serverless you want to exlude everything and you say that each function will include their own files.

Inside each function I include everything inside a specific folder (as `dist`) and then to exclude specific files as files ending with `.map` or, for example, the `aws-sdk` library inside node modules.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the package and `exclude` configuration for more control over the packaging process.

Add this to your serverless.yml:

```
package:
  include:
    - node_modules/**
    - lib/** 
functions:
  yourfunctionname:
    handler: api/manageclient/addclient/handler.handler
```

For more information on including/excluding folders: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging/

Comment: Can you please share exact structure of serverless.yml file for deploying functions , I have updated question with  code snippet .

Answer (score 3):

change your serverless.yml file like this:

```
package:
  exclude:
    -./**
  include:
    -node-modules/**
    -lib/**
```

and in your function

```
function:
  functionname:
    handler: api/manageclient/addclient/handler.handler
    package:
      include:
       -api/manageclient/addclient/handler.js
```